# Rendering / Returning HTML5 Canvas in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a canvas using React.  The graphics inside the canvas would also be handled by Reacts `render` method.

The current code does render a canvas with the graphics I want.  But I am looking for a way to **return a canvas with my graphics** from within the `render` method.  The reason I want this, is cause I want this to work in "React Way".

Ideally, I would want my code to be something like this:

```
return(
  <div>
    <canvas id='my_canvas_with_graphics_rendered_in_react'></canvas>
  </div>
);
```

First, I want to know if this is even possible.  Or if I should look for an alternative.

Maybe Im missing the point of React, if that is the case please let me know.  I do hope there is a solution, because from what I've read React touts itself as the `V` in `MVC`.  That is why, if possible, this would be a perfect solution for what I'm trying to do.  I would not have to worry about the rendering inside my canvas.  I would simply supply the data to the component and React would re-render the changes.

I have marked of in the `return` statement where I believe the correct code should go.

The `HTML` code:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
</div>
```

The `jsx` code:

```
var MyCanvas = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        var line = this.props.lines;
        var ctx = this.props.canvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(line[0].x0, line[0].y0);
        // .... more code .....
        ctx.stroke();

        return(
            <div>
                /* *********************************
                ??? RETURN MY RENDERED CANVAS
                    WITH GRAPHIC LINES. ????
             This is where I want to return the canvas 
                *********************************  */
            </div>
        );

    }
});


var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var line1 = { x0: 0, y0: 10, x1: 20, y1: 30 };
var line2 = { x0: 40, y0: 50, x1: 60, y1: 70 };

var myCanvas = <MyCanvas canvas={ canvas } lines={ [line1, line2] } />;
React.render(myCanvas, wrapper);
```

Hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 21):

Your only error was that you were not familar with react refs.
try this:

```
class ConnectionChart extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        let canvas = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.myCanvas);
        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(200,0,0)';
        ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 55, 50);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <canvas ref="myCanvas" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

You might have get rid of the ES6 style but you get the idea.
Of cause u can paint in other methods too ^^

Comment: A note from React [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-string-attribute): _"Although string refs are not deprecated, they are considered legacy, and will likely be deprecated at some point in the future. [Callback refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute) are preferred."_

Comment: Good answer but they are considered legacy now see -> https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs

Answer (score 13):

Instead of using the `canvas` in your `render` method, you'd do something like this:

```
var MyCanvas = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function () {
    React.getDOMNode(this).appendChild(this.props.canvas);
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div />;
  }
});
```

You just render an empty `div` and wait for React to mount that. When mounted, you append your canvas to the actual DOM node that React created.

The reason for this is that the `render` method only returns virtual DOM nodes that React then translates to real DOM nodes. And since you have a real DOM node, you can't convert that to a virtual node. Another reason for is that you should only return nodes from `render` that React controls. And since you're managing the canvas from outside of Reacts control, you should use real DOM apis do manage it.

Comment: First question: Does it matter if I call my graphics drawing routines in `componentDidMount` or `render`?

Comment: Second question: Would managing the canvas from within React (its creation and referencing) be more to Reacts way of doing things?  My idea is to make this component part of a larger set of React components.

Comment: First question: Yes, it matters. `render` can be called any number of times during the lifetime of the component instance, whereas `componentDidMount` will only be called once. Be sure to implement `componentWillUnmount` as well and do cleanup there.

Comment: Second question: Depends on what you want to do with the canvas. The problem is that the canvas API is imperitive and not declarative, so you'd need something like this to do it: https://github.com/Flipboard/react-canvas

Comment: Checked out the `react-canvas` link. It does seem that they've found a way  to do what I was trying to achieve.  Thanks for clearing things up by making the distinction between imperative and declarative explicit.  That was the core of my initial question.

Comment: Note that React.getDOMNode() is deprecated: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

Answer (score 9):

The key is overriding the right React lifecycle methods to do the drawing.  The render method creates the canvas DOM element and you can add a `refs` callback to set a reference to it, but you have to wait until the component is mounted to draw on the canvas.

Here's an example that uses a callback ref as the React docs recommend.  It is designed to render a static (non-animated) graphic component based on props and updates when props change.  It also subscribes to the window resize event so that it can be dynamically sized via CSS (such as `width: 100%`).  [This example is based on the code from this Gist.](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/6f7da234174ab9f64cce)

```
export default class CanvasComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this._resizeHandler = () => {
            /* Allows CSS to determine size of canvas */
            this.canvas.width = this.canvas.clientWidth;
            this.canvas.height = this.canvas.clientHeight;

            this.clearAndDraw();
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this._resizeHandler);

        /* Allows CSS to determine size of canvas */
        this.canvas.width = this.canvas.clientWidth;
        this.canvas.height = this.canvas.clientHeight;

        this.clearAndDraw();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this._resizeHandler);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (this.props.secondRect !== prevProps.secondRect) {
            this.clearAndDraw();
        }
    }

    clearAndDraw() {
        const ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        if (ctx) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
            this.draw(ctx);
        }
    }

    draw(ctx) {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(200, 0, 0)';
        ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);

        if (this.props.secondRect) {
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)';
            ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 50, 50);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <canvas ref={canvas => this.canvas = canvas} />
        );
    }
}
```

You can set the `secondRect` prop from the parent component or set it from state to see the component update when the prop updates.  You can extend this idea to build any kind of data-driven canvas rendering, such as a chart or graph.

Comment: I edited the example to also show the best practice of checking if relevant props or state changed in `componentDidUpdate` before redrawing the canvas.  If you don't check that the props or state actually changed, you may end up redrawing the canvas much more frequently than necessary.

Comment: This does not work anymore. Please update your answer to use createRef and this.canvas.current

Answer (score 8):

I thought I would update this answer using the `React.createRef()` because the `this.refs` is now legacy. [Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs)

```
import React from "react";
import * as PropTypes from "prop-types";

class Canvas extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.canvas = React.createRef()
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const ctx = this.canvas.current.getContext('2d')
        this.props.draw(ctx);
    }
    render() {
        return <canvas ref={this.canvas} />;        
    }
}
Canvas.propTypes = {
  draw: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
export default Canvas
```

You would use this `Canvas` by supplying the draw context.

```
<Canvas  
  draw={ctx => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(95, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    }
  }
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

I ported [@matthew answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54639206/1217998) to use React Hooks. React changes so frequently :)

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Canvas = ({ draw }) => {
  const canvas = React.createRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const ctx = canvas.current.getContext('2d');
    draw(ctx);
  }, [draw, canvas]);

  return <canvas ref={canvas} />;
};

Canvas.propTypes = {
  draw: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default Canvas;
```

You would use this Canvas by supplying the draw context.

```
<Canvas  
  draw={ctx => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(95, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    }
  }
/>
```